# how to include files from another server and process in another server in php?

Tags: php, mysql, server

I have to include or require files from one server to another solution through php code . Is there any way to do so

Comment: What you're asking is too broad and unclear. I think that now would be a good time for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Comment: What you want to achieve is possible but could open you up to some security vulnerabilities. You would have to open up including files remotely. `allow_url_include` setting

Comment: @shashank check https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214205688-allow-url-include

But as Rotimi Olawale stated, it is highly unsecure

Answer (score 1):

It's some kind of design flaw that you need to include some codes from another server.

Write code in your server or the other solution is using Web Services.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language.
Any PHP source file is (supposedly) processed inside the context of the Web Front (Apache, Nginx, etc.) in order to produce resulting, printable output (which is, in general, some HTML or JSON, but could also be an image binary or anything else).

The moment a Web front receives an HTTP request for a given PHP file, this file will get executed in-place, rather than its source dumped directly into the response stream.

If it is not so, then you have a serious misconfiguration in your Apache (or other) because it would mean that anyone can access your source files rather than your actual running application.

Therefore, it is the same for your own attempt to `include 'http://remote-server/remote-file.php' ;` : the remote server will receive an HTTP request, and will process the `remote-file.php`, and deliver the outcome to your requesting script. This is totally different from including a source file into your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

If files on that other server are not accessible, then `require` cannot include them.